# javascript: json push data to 2 dimensional json array according to respective id

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json

my requirement is first key consist of rating id and second key consist of array of of rating with respective data. 
as i tried this in JavaScript 2 dimensional array but we know JavaScript by default wont support 2 dimensional array.
so ineed this in json now.

input json:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Script Usage:- Call Opening , Closing, Prompts",
    "Rating_id": 42,
    "rating": "3",
    "rate_count": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "Script Usage:- Call Opening , Closing, Prompts",
    "Rating_id": 42,
    "rating": "5",
    "rate_count": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Active Listening / Paraphrasing / Probing /  Acknowledgement / Understanding  / Interruption",
    "Rating_id": 43,
    "rating": "3",
    "rate_count": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Active Listening / Paraphrasing / Probing /  Acknowledgement / Understanding  / Interruption",
    "Rating_id": 43,
    "rating": "5",
    "rate_count": 4
  }
]
```

output fomat i want in new json :

```
    [ 
        {"42": {
                  "3" : {
                "title": "Script Usage:- Call Opening , Closing, Prompts",
                "Rating_id": 42,
                "rating": "3",
                "rate_count": 2
              },
                 "5" : {
                "title": "Script Usage:- Call Opening , Closing, Prompts",
                "Rating_id": 42,
                "rating": "5",
                "rate_count": 5
              }}
            },
             { "43" :
            { "3": {
              "title": "Active Listening / Paraphrasing / Probing /  Acknowledgement / Understanding  / Interruption",
                "Rating_id": 43,
                "rating": "3",
                "rate_count": 3
              },
               "5" : {
                "title": "Active Listening / Paraphrasing / Probing /  Acknowledgement / Understanding  / Interruption",
                "Rating_id": 43,
                "rating": "5",
                "rate_count": 4
              }}
            }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const input = [
  {
    "title": "Script Usage:- Call Opening , Closing, Prompts",
    "Rating_id": 42,
    "rating": "3",
    "rate_count": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "Script Usage:- Call Opening , Closing, Prompts",
    "Rating_id": 42,
    "rating": "5",
    "rate_count": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Active Listening / Paraphrasing / Probing /  Acknowledgement / Understanding  / Interruption",
    "Rating_id": 43,
    "rating": "3",
    "rate_count": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Active Listening / Paraphrasing / Probing /  Acknowledgement / Understanding  / Interruption",
    "Rating_id": 43,
    "rating": "5",
    "rate_count": 4
  }
]

let output = {}
input.forEach(obj => {
  if (!output[obj['Rating_id']]) {
    output[obj['Rating_id']] = [obj]
  } else {
    output[obj['Rating_id']].push(obj)
  }
})

console.log(output)
```